# Entire content has been converted to table of contents

Tags: microsoft-word

So I was doing my assignment and I was fiddling out with the table of contents of word and I saved, closed and went away. Now when I open the entire content has somehow become the table of content and I can't undo it. There are pictures and charts so I could not just do the copy text only option. Please help!

This happened!
[image]

Comment: This does not look like a table of contents?!

Answer (score 0):

First, you can see if Word will allow you to restore the document. Click on File in the ribbon, then in the Info page that comes up look for Manage Document. Click that button, then click the Recover pop up and Word will look for any unsaved changes. You can then choose if you want to recover.

Did you choose Automatic or Manual Table of Contents? The reaction to these steps will likely be different for each type. If there are no unsaved changes, then:

- Save a copy of the document.
- Open the original document, go to the References menu, choose Table of Contents in the ribbon. In the drop down menu you will see an option "Remove Table of Contents", click that.
- Then, choose Table of Contents again and select one of the automatic TOC types. (I would recommend automatic because the manual one you have to be very careful to create sections and select the right headers for Word to generate a TOC.)

I can't tell you exactly what will happen because I don't know what changes you made to the original TOC.  What I am hoping for is that by removing and then re-creating the table of contents you get your document back the way it should be.

Comment: And don't forget to backup your documents!